# Problems with NMinimize in identifying dynamic system parameters

Tags: mathematical-optimization

[image]
I'm trying to identify the system's $K,T_1,T_2,T$.

First I define the system

```
tf = TransferFunctionModel[(
K E^(-T s))/((Subscript[T, 1] s + 1) (Subscript[T, 2] s + 1)), 
s] /. {K -> 2, Subscript[T, 1] -> 1, Subscript[T, 2] -> 20, 
T -> 0.8};
```

Here are the inputs that I've applied to the system, which you can ignore：

```
n = 8;
A = 4;
Nn = 500;
Evaluate[R /@ Range[n]] = Table[1, n];
If[R[n] == 1, u[1] = -A];
If[R[n] == 0, u[1] = A];
Do[
 temp = R[1];
 R[1] = BitXor[R[n - 2], R[n]];
 Do[
  temp1 = R[j];
  R[j] = temp;
  temp = temp1,
  {j, 2, n}
  ];
 If[R[n] == 1, u[i] = -A];
 If[R[n] == 0, u[i] = A],
 {i, 2, Nn}
 ]
```

Based on the above code, I got the function for `u` on the integer region from `1 to 500` and then I entered it into the system

```
tf = ToDiscreteTimeModel[tf, 0.1];
ss = StateSpaceModel[tf];
ydata = OutputResponse[ss, Table[u[k], {k, 1, 500}]];
tdata = Range[0, 500 - 1] 0.1;
ListPlot[Transpose[{tdata, ydata[[1]]}]]
```

[image]

My objective function is defined as the error between the output that I obtained above and the output that I obtained while using as an estimation parameter：

```
 fun[K0_?NumericQ, T1_?NumericQ, T2_?NumericQ, T_?NumericQ] := Module[
  {yhat, tf0, ss0, s},
  tf0 = TransferFunctionModel[(K0 E^(-T s))/((T1 s + 1) (T2 s + 1)), 
    s];
  tf0 = ToDiscreteTimeModel[tf0, 0.1];
  ss0 = StateSpaceModel[tf0];
  
  yhat = OutputResponse[ss0, Table[u[k], {k, 1, 500}]];
  Return[(yhat[[1]] - ydata[[1]]) . (yhat[[1]] - ydata[[1]])]
  
  ]
```

But in the end, there is an error while using NMinimize

```
  NMinimize[{fun[K0, T1, T2, T], 0 <= K0 <= 30, 0 <= T1 <= 30, 
  0 <= T2 <= 30, 0 <= T <= 1}, {K0, T1, T2, T}]

(* Take::take: can't extract position 0 to 499 in {0,0,0,0,0,0,0.,0.,-4.,<<497>>}. *)
```

Comment: It looks like something is going wrong inside your `fun`. Perhaps add some debugging statements within that function (with `Echo`) to see how far it goes without error and to pinpoint where the error is coming from. I suspect `OutputResponse` but I don't know enough about these functions to dig deeper.

Comment: Yes, I found out that it was due to an internal state function parameter issue, which could be a bug, thanks for the answer!